# how to mock an elasticsearch object in pytest test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, elasticsearch, pytest

I have a class that handles the connection to elasticsearch and uses the [elasticsearch library](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py) .
I am trying to mock an elasticsearch object using the [pytest_elasticsearch](https://github.com/ClearcodeHQ/pytest-elasticsearch) in pytest unit tests.
I am not really sure how to go about this.

I tried this:

```
import pytest
from pytest_elasticsearch import factories    
elasticsearch_proc = factories.elasticsearch_proc(port=-1,
                                                      index_store_type='fs')
    elasticsearch = factories.elasticsearch('elasticsearch_proc')
    class TestSuccessResponses:
        @pytest.fixture()
        def create_es_index(self, elasticsearch):
            elasticsearch.indices.create(index='test-index')
        def test_insert_record(self, elasticsearch):
            elasticsearch.create('test-index', '1', {'id': '1',
                                                     'type': 'Scrambled'}, refresh=True)
            custom_query = {"size": 10, "query": {"match_all": {}}}
            actual_response = es_client.client_query(elasticsearch, 'test-index', custom_query)
            print(actual_response)
```

I am getting this error:

```
test setup failed
self = <[AttributeError("'ElasticSearchExecutor' object has no attribute 'command'") raised in repr()] ElasticSearchExecutor object at 0x7fb8289d4fa0>
```

I don't know how to resolve this and how to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

I managed that using `aioresponses` (https://github.com/pnuckowski/aioresponses) and mocked directly the HTTP requests supposed to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import mock
import pytest

#from mock patch elasticsearch to get the transcript

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def es():
    es_mock = mock.patch('elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.get')
    return es_mock

def test_get_transcript(es):

    es.return_value = {
        "_source ": {"transcriptid": "78376763-c9d4-455e-a093-ae3cbcfe8a6b",
        "multiple_speaker_term":[
            {
                "speaker": 1,
                "start": 0.0,
                "end": 1.0,
                "content": "hello world",
            }]}
    }
    assert es.return_value != None
    print(es.return_value)
```

#You can also pass an object to read the .json file as es.return_value

[image]